# How to update a certain tuple element within a list of tuples?

Tags: haskell, tuples

Haskell beginner here.

I have a list of tuples type `(a, b)` like so: `[(1, "One"), (2, "2")]`, and a single pair `(key, value)`.

I want to create a recursive function that accepts a pair and a list of tuples all type `(a, b)` and returns the list after replacing all values associated to the passed key with the passed value:

```
changeTup :: (Eq a) => (a,b) -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
```

Example output:

```
> changeTup (1, "Hello") [(1, "One"), (2, "Two")] 
=> [(1, "Hello"), (2, "Two")]
```

I did some digging and it seems like the best way to do this is with `map`. I tried this but haven't gotten any good results.

This is my code:

```
changeTup :: (Eq a) => (a,b) -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
changeTup (y,z) [] = [(y,z)]
changeTup (y,z) (x:xs) = map replace
    where replace (key, value)
            | y == key    = (key, z)
            | otherwise   = (key, value)
```

I'm not sure how to approach increments the list `(x:xs)` within `map`. I'm getting an `expected type error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing about the `map` function is that iterating over a list (or another vaguely list-shaped thing) is its entire job. In the code you have, you have a perfectly fine `replace` function, and you want to apply to the elements of the list `(x : xs)` - and doing that is as simple as `map replace (x : xs)`

Comment: dang i feel like an idiot, thank you!

Comment: It gets even better. The two cases (`[]` and `x:xs`) are not needed. The single case `changeTup (y, z) xs = map replace xs where ...` alone is enough, or even `changeTup (y, z) = map replace where ...`.